# How can i get the route from blueprint xml file

Tags: java, apache-camel, osgi, blueprint

I have some problem. I need to take the route or all CamelContext from blueprint file. How can i did it? 
route.xml

I have tried to add route via RouteDefinitions but it throws exceptions because it expected spring namespace but i use blueprint namespace. I use cxf as implementation of JAX-RS. There is another way how to do it better.

```
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd">


<bean id="weatherMailService" class="com.test.mail.MailSenderImpl"/>

<service ref="weatherMailService" interface="com.test.mail.MailSender"/>

<bean id="serviceProcessor" class="com.test.mail.MailSenderImpl"/>

<bean id="context" class="com.test.mail.MailSenderImpl"></bean>


<camelContext id="ctx" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
    <route id="mail">
        <from uri="direct:start"/>
        <setBody>
            <constant>Test</constant>
        </setBody>
        <setHeader headerName="subject">
            <simple>Weather</simple>
        </setHeader>
        <process ref="serviceProcessor"/>
        <to uri="smtps://smtp.gmail.com:465?username=RAW(*****@gmail.com)&amp;password=******&amp;to=******@gmail.com"/>
        <to uri="log:start"/>
        <process ref="context"></process>
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

I would like to get CamelContext in java code. How can i did it? Thank you

Comment: What sort of Java code are you looking at? If it is your processor, then you can get the context from the exchange parameter the processor is passed, and use the `getContext()` method on the exchange.

Comment: I have a rest service that produce weather forecast. And i want to send an email when somebody call my service. Thank you for answer. When uri from = "direct:start: my process method doesn't execute. Also i want to set body dynamically in my route